# My app doesn't receive Foursquare push notifications

Tags: push-notification, foursquare

I have a problem with Foursquare API push notification.

I'm using foursquare real time push notification, but it's quite hard to test it. I can send test pushes to my Web application, and everything seems to work fine, the status is OK, and I see received info in my logs. But push notifications from the real account never come, there is no info in the logs.

I use the "Push checkins at venues managed by this app's users" type of pushes. I have registered my own foursquare venue with type home (private location), but when I check-in to this location, I don't receive any push.

Hovewer, when I switch push type to "Push checkins by this app's users", it works fine.
I am confused — why don't I receive pushes for my home location? Is it not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users do not "manage" their home venues. A managed venue refers specifically to businesses that have been claimed by their owners. If you would like to receive push notifications on home check-ins, you should configure your app to receive push notifications from all check-ins.

Answer (score 0):

You can "manage" a home-venue. But you have to "claim" it is yours, as you would have to for a business-venue.

On the details page of your venue is a link at the lower right "claim it now". Click it and finish all steps. On the last step you either pay $20 to be verified immediately or you choose that foursquare sends you a postcard/letter via traditional mail (3-4 weeks) with a verification code. If you use the latter, make sure the address of the venue that foursquare will use can be found by the postman.

After you have successfully claimed your venue foursquare will send you push-notifications.

I just did that recently see a [video of my Party-Greeting-Machine](http://youtu.be/ZtS7Yx_XI0c) here. There is also a german [blogpost](http://bit.ly/11RMEbg) about the small experiment (with some code).